# Move a div using keypresses and jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, so I'm trying to make a simple script that moves down a div when I press 's' but it's not firing at all. I got Jquery installed, and the error-console in FF isn't saying anything. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

http://prime.programming-designs.com/designs/map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put `//` before your HTML open comment tag `<!--`

You shouldn't use HTML comment tags for scripts anyway, the best method for inline styles/scripts is to use the `CDATA` element as follows:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
//your code in here
/* ]]> */
```

This does a number of things:

- allows XML entities to not need to be escaped
- use of multi-line comments prevents any newline issues that may result in your script being parsed (CMS's will often adjust white-space)
- creates valid XML when used in XHTML

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the jquery.hotkeys extension to bind to the key events:
https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code:

```
$('#map').keydown(function(event) {
    switch (event.keycode) {
        case 83: // left arrow key
            markX = markX + markSpeed;
            mark.style.top  = markX + 'px';
            break;
    }
});
```

The issues are that `keycode` needs to be camelCase `keyCode` and that the `case` should be `37` for the left arrow or `40` for the down arrow.